# PHP If Both Variables are 0

Tags: php

Why is it echoing 'both variables 0'

https://3v4l.org/E530h

```
<?php

  $QuantityOrdered = '1';
  $QuantityShipped = '0';
  echo '<br />' . $QuantityOrdered . ' & ' . $QuantityShipped . '<br />';

  if ($QuantityOrdered != '0' && $QuantityShipped != '0') {
    echo 'at least one variable is not 0';
  }

  else {
    echo 'both variables 0';
  }
```

Trying to get it so that if BOTH `$QuantityOrdered` and `$QuantityShipped` are 0, it goes to the else statement.

If `$QuantityOrdered` and `$QuantityShipped` are anything other than BOTH 0... for example, `0` and `1` (as in my example).. or `1` and `1`, `2` and `2` etc...

anything other than both being 0, it goes to the if statement.

Comment: you more than likely want `||` (OR) since `$QuantityOrdered` will never equal 0; it's 1 right now.

Comment: But I don't want to check if `$QuantityOrdered` OR `$QuantiyShipped` is 0, only if `$QuantityOrdered` AND `$QuantiyShipped` are 0

Comment: take it up with the answer given below then; it's no different than mine.

Comment: I'd change it around .. if ($QuantityOrdered == '0' && $QuantityShipped == '0' ) { echo 'both 0'; } else { echo 'at least 1 is not 0'; } .. easier to my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to visualise logical conditions like this is as a truth table:

```
  | 0 | 1
--+------
0 |   |  
--+---+--
1 |   |
```

Across the top, we have the possible values of `$QuantityOrdered`; down the side, the values of `$QuantityShipped`. In the grid, we put the result of the expression; I'll use T for true and F for false.

For your current condition, `$QuantityOrdered != '0' && $QuantityShipped != '0'`, we get this:

```
  | 0 | 1
--+------
0 | F | F
--+---+--
1 | F | T
```

We are using 1 to mean "not 0", so the only combination that's true in our table is where both variables are 1.

But what you actually wanted was this:

```
  | 0 | 1
--+------
0 | F | T
--+---+--
1 | T | T
```

You wanted the condition to be true in all cases except for one, the case where both variables are 0.

One way to write this would be to start with the opposite. For `$QuantityOrdered == '0' && $QuantityShipped == '0'` we get this:

```
  | 0 | 1
--+------
0 | T | F
--+---+--
1 | F | F
```

So we could write `! ( $QuantityOrdered == '0' && $QuantityShipped == '0' )`.

It turns out this is equivalent to `$QuantityOrdered != '0' || $QuantityShipped != '0'`. Fill in the table, and you'll see.

This equivalence, where "NOT (a AND b)" is equivalent to "(NOT a) OR (NOT b)", is called ''De Morgan's Law''.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use OR condition like this, if you use && (and) condition then both condition need to true so if $QuantityOrdered != '0' true and $QuantityShipped != '0' true then execute this code so your both condition need to true 
so this condition not work

```
 if ($QuantityOrdered != '0' && $QuantityShipped != '0') {
  echo 'at least one variable is not 0';
}
```

if you want to check one value true then execute this code then use or (||) condition

```
if ($QuantityOrdered != '0'|| $QuantityShipped != '0') {
  echo 'at least one variable is not 0';
}
else {
 echo 'both variables 0';
 }
```

for more information

http://www.w3resource.com/php/operators/logical-operators.php

Comment: [I like my "explanation" better...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124204/php-if-both-variables-are-0#comment73327557_43124204)